# How can I make radio buttons next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I got the problem that i want to have 2 radiobuttons next to each other. but one below the other.

```
<div class="backgroundOverlay cShow" ng-show="isShownUser">
    <div class="dropDown positionPopUp inpuBlock" id="add">
        <div class="inputBlock">
            <h1 class="popupTitle">{{titlePopup}}</h1>
            <div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
                    <input placeholder="login" ng-model="currentUser.login">
                </div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
                    <input placeholder="Vorname" ng-model="currentUser.Vorname">
                </div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
                    <input placeholder="Nachname" ng-model="currentUser.Nachname">
                </div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
                    <input placeholder="password" ng-model="currentUser.password">
                </div>
                <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace cRadioAdmin">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="Admin">Ja</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="Admin">Nein</label>
                <div class="cClearFloat cButtonsUser">
                    <button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="showAlert()">Speichern</button>
                    <button class="cButtonAbbrechen" ng-click="isShownUser = false">Abbrechen</button>
                </div>
```

can someone help me pls.

[image]

Comment: They ARE next to each other. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: this js fiddle is empty :) but not on my page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dstzont0/

Comment: They are already next to each other. May be other css effect on this.

Comment: i checked it with the other css classes but nothing happed it's still the same.

Comment: @MrSolution if you don't share the css, all the solutions you'll obtain will be especulations, and you will lost a lot of time of yours and of ours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between inline elements and block elements.
Using a div instead of your label to wrap the input will do the job.
Like this:

```html
<div><input type="radio" name="Admin">Ja</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="Admin">Nein</div>
```

You could also use the css, like this:

```html
<label style="display:block"><input type="radio" name="Admin">Ja</label>
<label style="display:block"><input type="radio" name="Admin">Nein</label>
```

Similarly you can use display:inline to force inline(in case some other css is affecting this)

Comment: now the radio buttons are on the left side and the text in the middle :)

Comment: you want the radio and text in center?